# iOS 11 : Crash with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios11

In iOS 11, when I push a ViewController that contains a scroll view, my app crashes. Why?

Code to push:

```
let programViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProgramViewController") as? ProgramViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(programViewController!, animated: true)
```

Error:

> -[UIView adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fca395ed440 2017-09-21 21:01:53.203465+0200
>   ApplicationName[1980:45337] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fca395ed440'

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    switch self.typeContent {
    case "news" :
        let listNews = self.listObjects as! [NewsArticle]
        let webViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as? WebViewController
        webViewController!.url = listNews[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].link
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController!, animated: true)
    case "program":
        let part = self.listObjects[indexPath.section] as! ProgramPart
        let event = part.listEvents[indexPath.row]
        let programViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProgramViewController") as? ProgramViewController
        programViewController?.paramsList = ["event_id": "\(event.id)"]
        programViewController?.delegate = cell as? FollowEventDelegate
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(programViewController!, animated: true)
    default :
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: above push action written in button action?

Comment: No, when select a tableViewCell.

Comment: So you written in didSetRowAt Index method.Can you please share your code?

Comment: What stack frame is trying to call `-[UIView adjustedContentInset]`?

Comment: There seems to be something in your storyboard that should be a `UIScrollView` but is in fact a plain old `UIView`.

Comment: Why are you setting a view controller's delegate as a _cell_? Cells go in and out of existence and are reused; that's a crazy architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, inside my UIScrollView, I had a UIView that contained all the others UIView. So I deleted it to put all UIView directly into the UIScrollView and I pre-farewell more to handle the constraints.
Thanks to Rmaddy for bringing me to the question.